# Javascript doing an Integer to Array conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an variable in javascript, called `id_equipamento`.

When i do this:

```
id_equipamento = 75;
var chips = new Array();

$("table#sample_1 > tbody > tr").each(function(index, row) {
var chip = {
    "id_tracker": id_equipamento,
    "id_chip": $(row).attr("id")
};
console.log(id_equipamento);
chips.push(chip);
    delete chip;
});
```

Before each, the id_equipamento is 75, but when i do this:

```
var chip = {
"id_tracker": id_equipamento,
"id_chip": $(row).attr("id")
};
```

The `id_equipamento` turns in `Array`, in `console.log` i see the follow output:

```
["75"]
```

But i'm not doing any conversion. Why JS do that?

Comment: I don't see any reason why `id_equipamento` would turn into an array. Maybe it's just the browser displaying the value being logged that way, since you're calling console.log inside a loop.

Comment: Would You, please, create a fiddle to play with? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I'm thinking the same thing that @sroes is . . . what browser are you using?  Testing in FireBug, I see an integer in the log for `id_equipamento`.

Comment: [The `delete chip` is pointless](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)

Comment: Side note:  If I log `typeof(id_equipamento)` I get "number" returned, as well.

Comment: I use other solution, but thanks.